# Outlook vba codes saved under application_reminder does not always work

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I designed an easy solution to let a team of five automatically informed about if team's daily critical tasks are completed or not.  I create a seperate task for each of them and set tasks' reminders same as the tasks'time (0 minutes before). 
Structure is like this; 
task owner completes task, takes screenshot (as a proof. this is a must) and saves it with a predefined file name in a specific folder (file.jpg).
Related outlook task reminder pops out, run codes to look for this file and if it finds the file, does nothing; if the file does not exist, sends team an e-mail saying task is not completed. 
Codes are saved under outlook's application_reminder, and I also have a couple of functions saved under a module. 
Codes are working well after triggered by task reminders for the first one or two instances but then for some reason stops working. Reminder pops out but codes do not run.

1. Any idea why codes are not working?  Is there a fix or something
   regarding this issue?
2. Any other solutions you know, doing what I am trying to do.
3. Can I convert this to a vsto project? Could this be a more effective
   solution? (I did nothing in visual studio up to now, but i want to
   start using it)

I pasted codes below just for your information.  As I said codes work for very first instances.  But improvement suggestions always welcome.

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim objPeriodicalMail As MailItem
    If Item.Categories = "Screenshot" Then
        Call Screenshot(Item.Subject)
    End If

End Sub
*************************
Function reppdate() As Date  'returns previous working date
Dim yest As Date
Dim tatiller As Variant
tatiller = Array("19.05.2020", "06.05.2020", "05.05.2020", "04.05.2020", "01.05.2020", "01.01.2020")  'local holidays
j = -1

For i = 0 To UBound(tatiller)
    yest = Format(DateAdd("w", j, Now()), "dd.mm.yyyy")
    If yest = tatiller(i) Then
            If Weekday(yest) = 2 Then
                j = j - 3
            Else: j = j - 1
            End If
    Else
        If j < -1 Then
        Exit For
        Else: End If
    End If
Next i
reppdate = yest
End Function
**************************************
Sub Screenshot(dosya As String)
yestt = reppdate()
Dim objMsg As MailItem
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
vamsg = "Dikkat, " & dosya & ".jpg bulunamadi, rapor gönderilmemis mi!"
dosyaadi1 = "c:folder\" & Format(yestt, "yyyymm") & "\Daily\" & Format(yestt, "dd") & "\" & dosya & ".jpg"
baglanti = "<a href=" & dosyaadi1 & ">" & vamsg & "</a>"

            If FileFolderExists(dosyaadi1) = False Then
            msg = vamsg
            Else
            End If

      objMsg.To = "vvvvv.com"
      objMsg.Subject = msg
      objMsg.Body = msg & " - " & dosyaadi1
      objMsg.Send

      Set objMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Update: I have spotted that the category "Screenshot" which I assigned for specified tasks had been disappeared oddly.  Now I re-assigned the categories and works fine for now.  I will keep you posted if it fails again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `Categories` property value may include another string categories assigned. So, I'd suggest checking a substring with a particular value instead.

```
Contains = InStr(strBaseString, strSearchTerm)
```

`Categories` is a delimited string of category names that have been assigned to an Outlook item. This property uses the character specified in the value name, sList, under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International in the Windows registry, as the delimiter for multiple categories. To convert the string of category names to an array of category names, use the Microsoft Visual Basic function `Split`.

2. I'd suggest running the code under the debugger and see how it works and where it fails. Also, you may add an error-handling routine, see [Error Handling in VBA](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/error-handling-in-vba).
3. There is no direct migration. Basically, you must create a new add-in project and add your event handler there. Then you can mode the code from VBA event handlers to the add-in's ones. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa830702(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN and [Create VSTO Add-ins for Office by using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/create-vsto-add-ins-for-office-by-using-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Comment: thank you for response.  Please see my update under org question.

Comment: Beside this, I just want to be sure about your response #2 (error handling).  Currently there is no error handling routine in my code.  Also there is no "on error resume next" or other error message suppression.  In case of an error occurrence I should have seen the outlook's error message pop out to my screen, am I right?  I am taking this as a suggestion on good coding practice though.